# cmd.exe doesn't kill a process with ctrl+c

Tags: windows-10

I'm running a python script from cmd. As long as it's in the python context, it breaks fine. However, when there's a call from the script to run something in matlab, the ctrl+c isn't processed until matlab finishes.

It used to break immediately until recently when I repair-upgraded win10 (which has endless annoying such bugs).

---

I've just noticed (oops) that I've been using cygwin's tee, which suppresses ctrl+c. Using powershell's instead resolves that.
(So this one isn't related to win10 bugginess.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069211/how-to-make-a-windows-command-output-to-be-displayed-on-console-and-to-write-int

Comment: Ctrl + C is specific to console programs. Windows will handle it and terminate a process if the program doesn't register a Ctrl+C handler. It means nothing in a graphical program although GUI guidelines say if text is selected it should copy to clipboard.

Comment: You mean ctrl+c is specific to a console like cmd.exe, which the question refers to.

Answer (score 0):

STRG-C must be implemented. You should add a listener in your Python script that interrupts on "STRG+c". When this event happens, end the subprocess call to Matlab.

Comment: I've already added a handler to SIGINT in python. It's never called when in matlab. Moreover, if I don't handle it, then the default behavior should be termination.

Comment: Only if you are in a console. If there is no console then Ctrl+C means nothing.